# Regex listview items from database

Tags: c#, wpf

Hello in my last post you can see i have asked something about regex and it worked.

ive changed the code from getting the files from folders to a Database now my regex does not work obviously.

this is the code of how i fill my listview

```
   public void DataFromFolders3(string fileName = "*")
    {

        LV3.Items.Clear();

        SqlDataReader dr;
        string query = "select * from tblBestanden2 WHERE datum LIKE " + "'" + fileName + "'";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

        con.Open();
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {

            LV3.Items.Add(dr["Name"]);

            Regex regex = new Regex("^zw1[0-9]*");

            if (regex.IsMatch(???))
            {
                LV3.Items.Remove(???);
            }
```

LV3 is my listview

i tried doing it like this

```
            if (regex.IsMatch(dr["Name"]))
            {
                LV3.Items.Remove(dr["Name"]);
            }
```

but it does not work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide example data, including one sample where it should match and one where it shouldn't?

Comment: it should not match zwaan123213   but it should match zw1324543 with the files in the Listview

Comment: What is your SQL Query returning?

Comment: The REGEX looks fine - do you have an example of a string where it doesn't work?

Comment: It just selects some File names which i have put in the Table and puts them in a listview

Comment: I know the Regex is fine but how do i apply it to the items in the ListView.

Comment: I don't understand, are you trying to fill a listview, or remove items from one that's already got items?

Comment: Im filling the listview with items from the query, then i want to remove the specific file name which matches the Regex

Comment: could you just exclude the file names in your sql query and not put them in the List View at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only issue with the code you posted is that a datareader returns objects and the other functions require strings. If you convert them like this, it should work.

```
        if (regex.IsMatch(dr["Name"].ToString()))
        {
            LV3.Items.Remove(dr["Name"].ToString());
        }
```

Even better, rather than adding and then removing, you could only add if they don't match.

```
Regex regex = new Regex("^zw1[0-9]*");
while (dr.Read())
{
    if (!regex.IsMatch(dr["Name"].ToString()))
    { 
        LV3.Items.Add(dr["Name"].ToString());
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much glad you could help me out!

Comment: @AhmadTI No worries - it just took me a while to work out where the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a SQL problem. It looks like you're passing in a filename of `*` to a LIKE clause, but that is a DOS wildcard. SQL uses `%` (and `_` for single characters)